# authorization header does not have the right format

Tags: c#, akamai

Akamai api using purge my url i got eror he authorization header does not have the right format

getting error response httpresponse any one tell how to add header authorization in c#  tell how to solve the issue ,,tell me how to call akamai api in our project  .i have accesstoken and cilent token secret key also how to add this token in this header section

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

public partial class Purge : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        purge();
    }

    public async static void purge()
    {
        var baseAddress = new Uri(" https://akab-wbrwrbgi6t5urrvg-ohjpi4v6gxsib5aa.purge.akamaiapis.net/");

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("akab-jbl3s3ptctwvocrr-3fawkhddo47udqlg");

          //  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false; 

            using (var content = new StringContent("{  \"objects\": [  \"http://hindi.eenaduindia.com/News/National/2016/03/15150007/video-viral-of-a-girl-creating-ruckus-in-hyderabad.vpf\" ],  \"action\": \"remove\",  \"type\": \"arl\",  \"domain\": \"production\"}", System.Text.Encoding.Default, "application/json")) 
            {
                using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("ccu/v2/queues/default", content))
                {
                    string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var b = responseData.Replace('"', ' ');
                    var r = b.Split(',', '\n');
                   // Response.Write(r[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of authentication are you using? Basic? OAuth?

Comment: i don't know what type of authentication using akamai ,I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an Akamai signing library.  There is a library for C# here:
    https://github.com/akamai-open/AkamaiOPEN-edgegrid-C-Sharp

The library's README includes sample code to get started integrating it into your system.

Thanks,
Kirsten

Comment: i am using this akamaiedgegrid auth .dll ,getting this error   Unexpected Response from Server: BadRequest Bad Request
title": "Bad request",
 "status": 400,
 "detail": "Invalid timestamp",

Comment: Your system is not sync'd to an ntp server.  Google for "ntp service <systemname>" to find instructions on how to do this.